# Is JS button slowing down my table generation?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with hundreds of rows, each containing a `<td>` element with a button like so:

```
<button onclick="editPerson(model.Id)">Edit</button>
```

And the `editPerson` function is something similar to this ajax call:

```
function editPerson(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Warranties/Edit/' + id,
        success: function (data){
            ... etc ...
        }
    });
}
```

I've just added this functionality (along with some others) and now generating my table seems to take forever. I figured that adding a button with a pointer would be completely fine - am I mistaken? Is the button pointing to the function generating / compiling some beefy code for each row or is it some other function I've added that is taking the toll (this is the most likely suspect, however)

Also, if this isn't optimal, yesterday I had a question related to something similar, and someone mentioned event delegation - so I think my idea is that I can put a listener on the entire table and then only activate the function if that click was on a particular element (i.e something that looks like a button but is actually just a placeholder on screen)

Comment: could you provide a code which reproduces issue? Also ev delegation is nice indeed, but I'd wonder about having a hundred of rows __displayed__...

Comment: Not clear how just specifying an onclick attribute could slow anything down dramatically - this doesn’t call the function at this point, nor should it create countless copies of the function or anything like that either. But yeah, using event delegation would be a good idea in any case. “Inline” event handling is ugly and from the last decade anyway :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought @CBroe - it's in a asp.net mvc framework and I'm just wondering if there's some "interference" in some of the processes there. I will try to cobble the event delegation anyway since it's good practice.

Comment: @grodzi if I don't figure it out soon I'll try to recreate the issue in a test project but for now it's a bit convoluted. I wonder if part of my issue is that I'm using datatables.net which means the whole table gets rendered before it applies pagination...

Comment: @jamheadart you should just write a dumb html with a function to be called on click. make 1k rows and check if perfs are as crappy as what you observe. I hint something else drags you down (which does not prevent you from thinking about an alternative to render less rows)

Comment: There was definitely something else dragging it down, repeated access calls for some data, which I've now fixed. The slowness seemed to still be there, but I fear it's just a Visual Studio compiling issue to start with. A few refreshes later it seems to speed up. The only way I can be sure is to deploy this to staging and make sure it's a good speed.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue when I was working with react, I have called the function on the onClick event, just like you have done

```
<button onclick="editPerson(model.Id)">Edit</button>
```

look carefully here you're not passing the editPerson function for the onClick event rather than you are calling it. So the function gets called before the event gets triggered, That's why it's making a mess.

Here's a solution rather than calling the function on the onClick event, you have to pass the function so whenever the onClick event gets triggered it will call it, just like below.

```
<button onclick="editPerson">Edit</button>
```

But here you will get another problem with the modal.id argument, When you are going to trigger the button have to pass an argument with that call and it will possible when you call the function under the empty function, just like below,

```
<button onclick="function() { return editPerson(model.Id)}">Edit</button>
```

This way you will be able to call the function on the onClick event of the button with an argument.

Comment: I tried this and now the button click doesn't work :/

Comment: let me check it, and I'll get back to you. As mentioned above I have implemented it with react and it's worked.